# Creating webpack bundle from custom directory files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am able to compile and run a react application using `public/src/index.js`. I want to create a completely different build from js files within `public/design/albert/js`. When I try compiling the file I get parse errors

My questions are:

- How do I build custom directory with an entry point in the directory (such as `public/design/albert/js/index.js`? **I'm having difficulty understanding multiple endpoints**
- How do I get babel-loader preset react to cooperate?

**I'd like as a result a separate build inside the dist folder from the code in albert/js that I can include in my scripts tag (I'm not using nodejs)**

Here is the webpack command I ran:

```
node_modules/.bin/webpack design/albert/js/index.js separate.js
```

I get **(it seems the babel-loader is not functioning)**:

Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (9:7)

```
   7 |   render(){
   8 |     return (
>  9 |        <div className="person">
     |        ^
  10 |        </div>
  11 |     )
  12 |   }
```

Here's my `design/albert/js/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Person from './person';

class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
       <div className="person">
         <Person />
       </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.querySelector("#app"));
//serviceWorker.unregister();
serviceWorker.register();
```

Here's my `design/albert/js/person.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Person extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
       <div className="person">
         <h1>Hello, I'm Jonathan</h1>
       </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Person;
```

Here's my `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports={
  devtool:'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: ['./src/index'],
  output: {
     path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
     filename: 'bundle.js',
     publicPath: ''
  },
  resolve:{
    extensions:['.js','.jsx']
  },
  module:{
    rules:[
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
    ]
  },
  //plugins:[new HtmlWebpackPlugin()]
};
```

Here's my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets":[
     ["env",{
       "targets":{
          "browsers":[
                "> 1%",
                "last 2 versions"
           ]
       }
     }],
     "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `webpack.config.js` file you can try something like this:

```
...
entry: {
  'bundle_1': 'src/index.js',
  'bundle_2': 'design/albert/js/index.js'
},
output: {
  filename: '[name].js'
  ...
```